# Output a value of a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

This may be a silly question but not sure how to go about working it.

I have this code working correctly

```
var values = [
  [20,25,35,40],
  [36,42,50,56],
  [42,56,52,68],
  [60,70,68,72]
];

function updateValue() {
   var ukValue = document.querySelector('input[name="uk_zone"]:checked').value;
   var frValue = document.querySelector('input[name="fr_zone"]:checked').value;

   if(ukValue && frValue) {
     alert(values[ukValue-1][frValue-1]);
   }
}
```

The alert is working fine but I am looking it to populate a text box instead of an alert box. Can anyone help?

Here is all my HTML

```
<form id="uk_zones" onChange="updateValue();">
<div><input type="radio" name="uk_zone" value="1">UK zone 1</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="uk_zone" value="2">UK zone 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="uk_zone" value="3">UK zone 3</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="uk_zone" value="4">UK zone 4</div>
</form>

<br />


<form id="fr_zones" onChange="updateValue();">
    <div><input type="radio" name="fr_zone" value="1">France zone 1</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="fr_zone" value="2">France zone 2</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="fr_zone" value="3">France zone 3</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="fr_zone" value="4">France zone 4</div>
</form>

<input type="text" id="text1" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What did you find out from your research? This is a pretty standard/[easily-searchable](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+populate+a+text+box) thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already stinking close, the same way you read out the data you can set (with value).  PS, this is tagged at jQuery but you're not using jQuery... also crazy duplicate of a few other questions.

```
function updateValue() {
   var ukValue = document.querySelector('input[name="uk_zone"]:checked').value;
   var frValue = document.querySelector('input[name="fr_zone"]:checked').value;

   if(ukValue && frValue) {
     document.getElementById('text1').value = [ukValue-1][frValue-1];
   }
}
```